# Appcelerator Alloy Click Event for Status Bar Icon

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

Is it possible to create a click event using the status bar icon [image]

Comment: would you like an event to be fired upon clicking the app icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a callback to the `onHomeIconItemSelected` property. Say you have a `Tabgroup` with a "tabGroup" id, it would be something like:

```
$.tabGroup.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    var activity = $.tabGroup.activity;
    // Avoid older APIs executing this code
    if( Ti.Platform.Android.API_LEVEL >= 11 ) {
        activity.actionBar.onHomeIconItemSelected = function() {
            alert("Home icon clicked!");
        };  
    }
}
```

For a more complete and detailed explanation, you could refer to https://github.com/websterj/Alloy2TabbedAndroidUI which is a good demonstration of an app using the Action Bar in Titanium.